# Why does my simple React form using hooks not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm learning the basics of React Hooks at the moment, I am wondering why this particular code does not work:

```
function Form() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  let result = '';
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    result = input;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Form practice</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <h2>{result}</h2>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I am simply expecting `<h2>{result}</h2>` to display what is being captured in `input` while the submit button is clicked. However, nothing happens. What is wrong with this logic?

Answer (score 2):

The way that a react component knows to rerender is that you set state. Changing the value of a local variable will not cause a rerender. So if you want the `<input>` to change separately from the `<h2>`, you will need to turn `result` into a piece of state.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [result, setResult] = useState('');
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setResult(input);
}
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <h1>Form practice</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        submit
      </button>
    </form>
    <h2>{result}</h2>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply because on each render of the component (whenever the state change, the component will render again) the code runs again and `result` will set to value 0.

Why not just render the `input` instead of the `result` variable?

```js
function Form() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    // do whatever you need to do to submit the form.
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Form practice</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <h2>{input}</h2>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi ye need to set the result with useState as well so that re-render happens

```
function Form() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [result,setResult]= useState('');
  const handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult(input);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Form practice</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <h2>{result}</h2>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

now u will be able to see the changes